# Storing selected tab for restoration using React Redux and Router

Tags: react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

Currently I have a sample which I'm working on which is a basic master details page. This sample uses `react-router-redux`. Within the details panel I have a number of tabs which use can see different facets of the selected item... all fairly standard stuff.

When the user selects an item from the master list, the URL that the clicked `<Link ... />` send them to is something like `customer/123`. Within the route that is registered for that url (i.e. `:id`), I have an `indexRoute` route which `replaces`s the route to default route/tab `/customer/${nextState.params.id}/address`.

All this works well and the user can navigate between tabs just fine. The problem comes when the user closes the detail window and selects a different detail. As expected, it opens the tab based on the route specified by the `indexRoute`. Under normal circumstances, this might be fine but I want it to remember which route was selected. I'm wondering if anyone has ideas on how this should be done?

I think I can do achieve this by registering a callback with the `onClick` event of the `Link` and dispatching an event which will result in `key` of the selected tab being saved in the `store`. Then within the `onEnter` of the `indexRoute` I can access the store and pull out this saved state and target the `replace` to this that item.

This should work but seems like a lot, just wondering if this seems right to other?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the same approach - dispatch an action when the tab is clicked and store the tab key in the store. 
Use mapStateToProps to retrieve the value.